# Snowflake Connectivity from .NetCore API Service

Tags: .net-core, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I have developed an Api service ( c# program) using .NetCore3.1. I have used Snowflake.Client dll library in my Api service to connect to Snowflake Database. We have 3 Snowflake accounts (i.e. Dev account, UAT account and PROD account). Recently, the Snowflake database name is changed in these 3 accounts and NOW the database name is not the same. For example, the database name is changed to DataWareHouse_DEV in Dev account, DataWareHouse_UAT in UAT account and DataWareHouse in PROD account.

Currently the Snowflake.Client library accepts only four parameters. see below code snippet

```
public SnowflakeClient(string user, string password, string account, string region = null);
```

My Configuration file:

```
 "SnowflakeSettings": {
   "Account": "AB4444",
   "User": "SOME_SERVICE_ACCOUNT",
   "Password": "Password@123!",
   "Region": "east-us.azure"
  }
```

Need help and inputs to handle the need:

I want to pass another parameter Databasename so that I can add it to the configuration. How do i pass another parameter besides the user, password, account and region? what is the appropriate library or methods i have to use for Snowflake connectivity?

Thanks
Vam

Comment: Is your existing database name configured, or is it hardcoded in the program?

Comment: Hi - in Snowflake you don't connect to a database, you connect to an account and then use the databases in that account

Comment: Yes I am connecting to a Snowflake account. But In my code i have hardcode the database name and I am connecting to a specific database in that Snowflake account. So trying to see if there is a option where we can configure database name and pass it as a parameter. 

Thank you

Comment: Hi, this may be a terminology issue but, to reiterate, there is no concept in Snowflake of “connecting to a database” so your statement “I am connecting to a specific database in that Snowflake account” makes no sense. Do you mean you want to set the query context to be a specific database - so that any queries will automatically be run against that database unless the query specifically defines another database?

Comment: I am connecting to a Snowflake account.  In my code i have hardcode the database name and I am fetching the data from that database.

Comment: I am connecting to a Snowflake account.  In my code i  have hardcode the database name in a query and I am fetching the data from that database.

Example:
var Query = $"SELECT WN.ANUMBER,  COUNT(DISTINCT WN.APPKEY) AS appkeycnt FROM DataWareHouse_DEV.DBO.VW_NUMBER WN
 join DataWareHouse_DEV.DBO.VW_DATA  Ic on Ic.APPKEY=WN.APPKEY
 WHERE WN.ANUMBER IN ({ANumberResult}) 
 AND WN.UNITKEY IN (SELECT IC.UNITKEY FROM DataWareHouse_DEV.DBO.VW_DATA IC WHERE IC.UNITNAME = '{businessUnitName}')
  GROUP BY  WN.ANUMBER HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT WN.APPKEY) = 1";